# Disable ENTER only in text input but allowed on the rest of the page

Tags: javascript, html, forms

have a simple form but when I disable the ENTER using

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.addEventListener('keydown',function(e).{if(e.keyIdentifier=='U+000A'||e.keyIdentifier=='Enter'||e.keyCode==13){if(e.target.nodeName=='INPUT'&&e.target.type=='text')
{e.preventDefault();return false;}}},true);
</script>
```

It disables the use of ENTER on the whole page,

how can I only PREVENT on (Can not modify input tag here, so adding ID wont work)

```
<INPUT CLASS=INPUT NAME=CASE3>
```

and ALLOW it on

```
<INPUT TYPE="button" value="Cases" onclick="javascript:pfkeyrtn('PF08')">
```

thank you

Comment: Use `document.getElementById('myInput').on('keydown', ...)`.

Comment: The first clue should probably be `window.addEventListener`, which ... wait for it.... adds an event handler to the top most element, the window.

Comment: Hi, unfortunately on the text input, I am not allowed to set an ID, so using your suggestion will not work for me.

Comment: adeneo, yes I figured that out and then tried <script type="text/javascript"> 
function stopRKey(evt) { 
  var evt = (evt) ? evt : ((event) ? event : null); 
  var node = (evt.target) ? evt.target : ((evt.srcElement) ? evt.srcElement : null); 
  if ((evt.keyCode == 13) && (node.type=="text"))  {return false;} 
} 
document.onkeypress = stopRKey; 
</script>

Comment: Hi, unfortunately on the text input, I am not allowed to set an ID, so using your suggestion will not work for me.    will this `FORM name="form" ACTION="" METHOD="" NAME=A  onkeypress="return event.keyCode !=13;"` be a better option? @adeneo

Comment: @Nammer My updated answer targets the input by name

Comment: Do you only want to prevent Enter on one specific text-input or all text-inputs? It is not really clear to me, since your title suggests for all text-inputs but your question might be for only `[name=CASE3]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[preventDefault()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) method tells the user agent that if the event goes unhandled, its default action should not be taken as it normally would be.

So instead of adding the eventListener to the window, attach it to the element itself.

```js
var inpt = document.querySelector("input[name='CASE3']");
inpt.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode === 13) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert("TADA!");
  }
});
```

```html
<input type="text" name="CASE3" />
```

Comment: howdy @kramb, unfortunately i cannot modifly add the ID to the INPUT as it is automatically generated by an engine. How would I lets say allow ENTER on all buttons instead?

Comment: I've changed the answer to allow for `name` instead of `id`

Comment: Hey, no problem! Don't forget to mark as answer **if** this fixes your initial question.

Answer (score 0):

Simply apply your listener to the `<input>` directly:

```
document.querySelector('#myInput').addEventListener('keydown', /* your func goes here */);
```

Answer (score 0):

Or use jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function(){
    $('#your-input').keydown(function(e) {
      if ( e.keyCode == 13 ) {
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

Like on [this Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1baap5xz/)

Answer (score 0):

Why not checking if the current focused element is an input element? Like so:

```
window.addEventListener( 'keydown', ( e ) => {
  const inputFields = [ 'textarea', 'input' ];
  const isButton = e.target.getAttribute( 'type' ) === 'button';
  if ( e.key === 'Enter' && inputFields.indexOf( e.target.nodeName.toLowerCase() ) && !isButton ) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
} );
```

Comment: OP has multiple `<input>`s and only wants to prevent enter in a specific one.